# Neither Mary nor Jane is/are beautiful

Tags: singular-vs-plural, negation

When two singular subjects are connected by "**neither...nor**", does it take a singular verb or plural verb? Which is more natural and acceptable?

> Neither Mary nor Jane **is / are** beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

A very clear explanation is [**here**](http://grammarguide.copydesk.org/2012/01/10/a-tricky-agreement-problem-neither-nor/):

> - When two subjects are joined by **neither-nor** or **either-or**, [...] **focus your attention on the noun closest to the verb**.
> - **If it is singular, as in the sentence above, choose the singular verb. If the noun is plural, choose the plural form of the verb.**

So the sentences below are correct:

> - Neither Mary nor **Jane is** beautiful.
> - Neither the boy nor **his sisters were** wearing seatbelts.

Answer (score 0):

*Neither Mary nor Jane **is** beautiful.*

This is the correct sentence. We use **singular verb forms after singular nouns** and **plural verb forms after plural nouns**.

Compare:

1. Neither the European Union nor the international community **is** to blame for this. (*European Union* is singular and *international community* is singular too)
2. Neither the photographs nor the lists **constitute** evidence of the actual claimed loss. (*photographs* is plural and *lists* is too)

Answer (score -1):

"Mary" and "Jane" both are single entities so "is" is to be used.

Comment: I think 'are' can also be used. What I'd like to know is which is more natural and acceptable.

Comment: I'm afraid, "are" cannot be used in your sentence. Please read my edited answer below. Thank you!